# How do I give players a potion effect when they reach a certain XP level?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to give players swiftness when they reach level 10. Then when they get to 20 they get another effect then 30 and 40 and so on I just don’t know how to do it.

Comment: In MCJava at least there's a target selector for XP levels.

Answer (score 1):

## Basics

Place a repeating command block and set it to `Always Active`. In the command input, type:

```
/effect @a[lm=10,l=20] speed 1
```

This will effect all players with a status effect between 10 and 20 levels with speed.

Repeat but change the `lm` and `l` numbers to set the level where the effect is applied. `lm` is the minimum amount needed to trigger, `l` is the maximum.

## Things You Can Change

Change the 2nd number after `speed` to change the effect's level. Note that it is a 0-based index, so for level 1 you type `0`, for level 2 you type `1`, and so on. Example:

```
/effect @a[lm=10,l=20] speed 1 1
```

to give the players speed II.

If you don't want the particles to show up simply add `true` to the end of the command:

```
/effect @a[lm=10,l=20] speed 1 0 true
```

## How it Works

The `@a[lm=10,l=20]` is the part that does the magic. That is where you select *who* you want the effect to be applied to. The `@a` selects all online players, and the part in `[]`s lets you narrow down your search.

`[l=20]` sets the maximum amount to target. `[lm=10]` sets the minimum. This means that anyone with a minimum of 10 levels and a maximum of 20 levels will be targeted.

The command only gives the effect for one second. But because the command block repeats every 20 times a second, it will keep giving the effect preventing it from running out.

---

If you want the effect to only be applied once for a certain time, it will be a bit harder. Please comment below if you would like that.

Comment: Note that if you want it to be one level, set the `l` and `lm` selectors to the same thing.